# Custom UITableViewCell editingAccessoryView?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4

Here's the dilemma:  I want to create a custom `editingAccessoryView` that contains two buttons for my stock `UITableViewCell`.  I'd like to achieve this using a storyboard.  So far I've followed the steps outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280940/loading-custom-uiview-in-uiviewcontrollers-main-view), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585681/custom-editingaccessoryview-behaving-unpredictable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012751/how-to-add-custom-editingaccessoryview-for-uitableview).  I just can't seem to get it to work.  The closest I got was when I created a xib of type `UIView`, set the class to that of my `UIViewController` that contains the `UITableView` and bound it to my `IBOutlet`, but on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it's `nil`.

Truth is, I think I just need to know how to create the view and then map it to the `editAccessoryView`; from there I believe I can figure out how to add buttons and map the corresponding `IBAction`.  Can anyone provide some step-by-step instructions or links to tutorials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this on my own with the following code:

```
    UIView *editingCategoryAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 35)];

    UIButton *addCategoryButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [addCategoryButton setTitle:@"Add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addCategoryButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 35)];
    [addCategoryButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addCategoryClicked:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIButton *removeCategoryButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [removeCategoryButton setTitle:@"Remove" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [removeCategoryButton setFrame:CGRectMake(55, 0, 65, 35)];
    [removeCategoryButton addTarget:self action:@selector(removeCategoryClicked:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [editingCategoryAccessoryView addSubview:addCategoryButton];
    [editingCategoryAccessoryView addSubview:removeCategoryButton];
    cell.editingAccessoryView = editingCategoryAccessoryView;
```

As you can see I created a new `UIView` programmatically and added two buttons via `addSubview` and then assigned it to the `editingAccessoryView`.

Comment: added bonus: by setting your own, you can also override the default left position.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is probably too late to help, but it is much better than the solution you found. iOS gives you a method named `tableView: editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:`. This method basically allows you to add your own UITableViewRowActions, which is much easier (and cleaner) than adding an entire UIView with UIButtons.

Apple says:

> Use this method when you want to provide custom actions for one of your table rows. When the user swipes horizontally in a row, the table view moves the row content aside to reveal your actions. Tapping one of the action buttons executes the handler block stored with the action object.
>
> If you do not implement this method, the table view displays the standard accessory buttons when the user swipes the row.

You can look at the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:) yourself, if you want.

#### Example (Swift)

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
    let customAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Your Custom Action", handler: { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) in
        println("Do whatever it is you want to do when they press your custom action button")
    })
    editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Delete", handler: { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) in
        println("You can even implement a deletion action here")
    })
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    
    return [deleteAction, editAction]
}
```